# L'« allochtone » : confusion polysémique et usage très contemporain ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, lexique, antonyme

Dans un article<sup>1</sup> on peut lire que :

> Jusqu'en 1985, le droit des femmes à ce statut [d'Indien] dépendait de
>   leur mari. Une femme qui épousait un homme sans statut perdait donc le
>   sien - et du même coup, le droit de vivre au sein de sa communauté. À
>   l'inverse, une femme **allochtone** obtenait le statut d'Indien en
>   épousant un homme reconnu comme tel par le gouvernement canadien.
>
> [ « [Un groupe réclame l'abolition de la Loi sur les Indiens](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/201902/16/01-5215026-un-groupe-reclame-labolition-de-la-loi-sur-les-indiens.php) »,
>   *La Presse*, 16 février 2019, je souligne ]

L'[*allochtone*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364107) est l'antonyme du mot *autochtone*, et désigne dans le domaine de l'ethnologie/sociologie la « **personne qui n'est pas née dans le pays qu'elle habite** » (GDT). On note de plus que :

> [...]
>   À partir des années 1990, le terme allochtone est parfois utilisé en
>   sociologie ou dans le vocabulaire politique pour remplacer des
>   expressions du type *issu de l'immigration* ou *d'origine étrangère*.
>   Toutefois, on désapprouve souvent cet emploi en raison des
>   connotations discriminatoires qui lui sont associées.
>
> Selon les pays et les territoires, les définitions du terme allochtone
>   sont adaptées à la dynamique particulière des groupes de chaque aire
>   géopolitique. Le concept fait ainsi souvent référence à un sens très
>   restreint du terme. Au Canada, par exemple, on distingue parfois les
>   personnes d'origine amérindienne ou inuite que l'on nomme *autochtones*
>   et les personnes d'autres origines que l'on nomme *allochtones*. Cet
>   usage est souvent critiqué en raison des risques de confusion entre
>   cette acception particulière et le sens premier du terme, toujours en
>   usage.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique de l'OQLF, « allochtone »,
>   consulté le 17 février 2019 ]

---

- Avec le contexte trouve-t-on qu'il y aurait confusion possible dans le propos de l'article (de *La Presse*), entre une femme qui n'est pas autochtone (« non-autochtone ») et une femme qui n'est pas née dans une communauté autochtone ?
- L'emploi d'*allochtone* pour la personne qui n'est pas née dans le pays
  qu'elle habite est-il encore en usage aujourd'hui (2019) ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> ...où l'on réclame l'abolition de la [*Loi sur les indiens*](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/lois/I-5/index.html) (du Canada) vu la [*Déclaration sur les droits des peuples autochtones des Nations Unies*](https://www.un.org/development/desa/indigenous-peoples-fr/drip.html), qu'appuie maintenant le Canada, et une [opinion](https://tbinternet.ohchr.org/Treaties/CCPR/Shared%20Documents/CAN/CCPR_C_124_D_2020_2010_28073_E.pdf) du *Comité des droits de l'homme des Nations Unies* reprochant au Canada d'avoir enfreint ses obligations internationales dans un contexte où l'on doit [uniformiser](https://www.parl.ca/LegisInfo/BillDetails.aspx?billId=8160636&Language=F) les lois du pays avec la *Déclaration*.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Je crois que les deux usages sont courants, mais que celui au sens de "non-autochtones" n'est pas utilisé en Europe (d'où son absence des dictionnaires, pour qui hors France, point de salut), pour la simple et bonne raison qu'en Europe, il n'y a pas de peuples qu'on qualifie d'"autochtones" (en dehors des Samis). Les autochtones, pour les Européens francophones, ce sont *des peuples qui existent ailleurs*, ils n'ont donc généralement pas besoin d'un terme pour dire "non-autochtone".

Comment: Dans ce contexte (_les peuples qui existent ailleurs_), le terme pour "non-autochtone" est "touriste".